# how to make usb into 2 partition for use

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, mount

Have an 8GB USB and want to make it as follow:
1-A 2GB as the first partition to make it bootable using the dd command.
2-All rest space as the second partition to use as USB drive to transfer data.

all i did is use:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`

in order to make it fully empty. After that used:

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`

to make 2 partitions. Also in `fdisk` program, i tagged a `bootable` to `sbd1` partition until here everything is okay. But I cannot mount partitions. the problem I have is I can mount with GUI program and use `Disks` in GUI but I want to use the command line.

The error i face is

```
moji@Lenovo:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1
mount: can't find /dev/sdb1 in /etc/fstab
```

If I use `disks` and format the drive making NTFS or other formats and format it it will be solved but I don't understand why it doesn't work in command prompt. I really got angry with Linux.

Don't understand man pages and all I see...everything in the example in the book will work but when I try, it doesn't work!!!

Boring Linux.

Comment: ``` 
moji@Lenovo:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Comment: Dear Charles, I used all command like lsblk, fdisk, blknd. But nothing worked. My problem is when I want to mount the partitioned Devices. Also I don't understand why error point me to /etc/fstab !!!!

Comment: The dd command does not create a standard partitioned drive. It is a hybrid DVD/flash drive that can be read. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb#Drives_-_mass_storage_devices This is mostly the dd or dd under the hood, but has other methods.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use the `lsblk` command first to see the disks and the partitions. If there is not something like **sdb1**, your partition operation is not correct.

Then you should do `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/user/somedir`